# Insert term description programmatically into hierarchical custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, description

I have following code and I want to specify a term description for each actor and director in `$tmdb_actors_arr` and `$tmdb_directors_arr`:

```
// build array
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $tmdb_title,
    'post_name' => $wp_movie_slug,
    'post_content' => $tmdb_plot,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_input' => array(
        'tmdb2wp_year' => $tmdb_date,
        'tmdb2wp_actor' => $tmdb_actors_arr,
        'tmdb2wp_director' => $tmdb_directors_arr
    ),
);
// insert post built from array above
$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

// instert custom fields
add_post_meta($post_id, 'tmdb_id', $tmdb_id, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'imdb_id', $tmdb_imdb, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'backdrop', $tmdb_backdrop, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'poster', $tmdb_poster, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'original_title', $tmdb_orig_title, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'tagline', $tmdb_tagline, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'trailer', $tmdb_trailer, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'og-image', $tmdb_poster, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'og-title', $tmdb_title, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'og-description', $tmdb_plot, true);

// insert genres as categories
wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $tmdb_genres_arr, 'category');
```

So how and where do I insert term descriptions for director 'Stephen Spielberg' and actors 'Marlon Brando', 'Morgan Freeman'?

Edit:

```
// Movie cast
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($tmdb_cast)) {
    $tmdb_actors_arr[] = $tmdb_cast[$i]['name'];
    $i++;
}

// Movie crew
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($tmdb_crew)) {
    if ($tmdb_crew[$i]['job'] === "Director") {
        $tmdb_directors_arr[] = $tmdb_crew[$i]['name'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Where you define `$tmdb_actors_arr` and `$tmdb_directors_arr` and what do this variables contain?

Comment: They contain names of actors and directors for movies, see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert them terms first using [`wp_insert_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term), then associate them to the post.

Comment: Do you have a basic example on how I could do this with the code I have now?